# php compare two date not work

Tags: php, date

I'm in a problem that i need an help because after research i have not found a solution.. I have to compare two date in PHP, the date of now with the date from Database.

Writing this:

```
strtotime(Date("d/m/Y H:i"))
```

Correct return the current timestamp.
But writing this:

```
strtotime($m['start_date'])
```

Work but response with a timestamp less than the current timestamp but the $m['start_date'] is from Database and it's like this: "2017-08-23 11:00:00"... It's not possible that the timestamp of 2017-08-23 11:00:00 it's less than the current timestamp!
And the weird part is that if i write this:

```
Date("d/m/Y H:i",strtotime($m['start_date']))
```

It response with the correct Date formatted with the string i passed to: 23/08/2017 11:00. How it possible? I have to compare the two timestamp but the output is that today come after tomorrow...
I have tested a lot of solution but not working at all. I have tried also to write this:

```
strtotime(Date("d/m/Y H:i",strtotime($m['start_date'])))
```

But not return nothing, 0.
I have also tried to put the second, but the result is the same.

I'm falling all for a stupid comparison from two date, help me!
After today i definitely hate work with Date

Comment: If Value of `strtotime(Date("d/m/Y H:i"))` is  `1512756000` then after 1 minute it would be `1512756060` which is less than previous

Comment: Guys here answered you, but I think you will be very satisfied with results of working with Carbon PHP - library designed for working with dates.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to compare two timestamps from why don't just use the `time()` function and compare if it's less, greater or equal to the timestamp of the value received from the database by using `strtotime($m['start_date'])` for example

```
$db_time = strtotime($m['start_date']);
if ( time() > $db_time ) {
    /**
    ** YOUR CODE
    **/
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's working now! Thanks! But i don't know why strtotime(Date("d/m/Y H:i")) not return the current timestamp..

Comment: @Riccardo I think it's because of the format you are using as in `date( 'd/m/Y H:i' )` so please check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) for the supported datetime formats